# Why JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)) removes a property of obj

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to clone an obj with some react elements inside. When I clone the obj
with JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)). It removes $$typeof: Symbol(react.element).

```
const elm = <span>A Simple Span</span>
console.log(elm)
const copyOfElm = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(elm))
console.log(copyOfElm);
```

I want to know how to clone in a way that it does not remove the property.

Comment: You might want to know more about javascript property descriptors. I think that explains why all properties aren't displayed in JSON.stringify, and why you cannot use it to clone everything.

Comment: `React.cloneElement`?

Comment: `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(something))` is not a reliable way to clone objects. It works *sometimes*, but as you've found it doesn't work all the time.

Comment: I want to know why $$typeof is not present in copyOfElm

Comment: [Because `JSON.stringify` ignores all `Symbol` properties.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol#Symbols_and_JSON.stringify())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) e.g.

```
const copyOfElm = Object.assign({}, elm);
```

Comment: what if i wanna clone object like `const elm = {
  innerHTML:[
    <span>A Simple Span</span>,
    <span>A Simple Span</span>
  ]
}`

Comment: Object.assign is for objects not loops. For this purpose you can try https://lodash.com/docs/#cloneDeep

Comment: Thanks umair i got my answer